# Can't receive emails using Postfix: Status=deferred (conversation with 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] timed out while receiving the initial server greeting)

Tags: postfix, email-server, centos6

I was setting up a server until about a month ago when I had to stop for personal reasons. I've went back to it today and tried to send/receive emails.

Initially, I sent myself an email from my Gmail account to an email account on my server and I received it successfully. However, when I have gone to reply back to that email I haven't received it in my Gmail account and nor have I received a bounce email to my email account on the server.

However, I have tried two more times to send emails to the server from the Gmail account and they haven't been received. I have also sent an email to the Gmail account again and again neither the message or a bounce message has been received.

I have checked the Postfix mail queue, and it shows the following information:
[image]

I have also checked the mail log, and I get the following error:

```
May 16 15:58:43 setanta postfix/smtp[9231]: DC06A122: to=<michael@gravex.co.uk>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1542, delays=1242/0.01/300/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (conversation with 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] timed out while receiving the initial server greeting)
```

Does anyone have an idea about what's going on with this?

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Here is the main.cf file. This is all uncommented, so if there is something missing here then it's either not included or I have it hashed.

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix   
command_directory = /usr/sbin    
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = setanta.gravex.co.uk, localhost, localhost.localdomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
myhostname = setanta.gravex.co.uk
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = maildrop
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
relayhost =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
```

Comment: Can you post your postfix main.cf file. Just the uncommented lines.

Comment: Amend that to `postconf -n`, and the logs from one entire message from connection to queue removal.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending mail to a service that postfix expects to be running on port 10024.

This process is not listening on port 10024; perhaps it is not running ?

Comment: Are you referring to `postfix`? It is set to start when the server starts and I've also stopped/restarted the service so it does run.

Comment: I am talking about this:  relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:**10024**

Comment: Sorry I know what that is. I've updated my answer.

Comment: WHat answer ? I thought you had a question - and you haven't done what I asked yet.

Comment: Sorry, having internet problems atm. Amavisd wasn't running but thats caused another issue. Will update later today.